# Custom cursor with .less

Tags: css, less, joomla2.5

I am using Joomla 2.5 with a Gantry-powered theme. I am trying to build a custom text type with .less, and I am way out of my depth.
The text is clickable, and that plays an audio file. Now I am looking for a clean way to be able to change the text attributes site-wide without editing every article every time. I am trying to make a custom class in a .less file that will change the mouse cursor on hover, but I can't get it to work at all.

Here is how I set up the audio:

```
<audio type="audio/mpeg" id="all" src="images/audio/BlackFriday/p2.mp3"></audio>
<div class="aa"><a onclick="document.getElementById('p2').play()">Black Friday sales are not all they are cracked up to be.</a></div>
```

I am trying to use the class "aa", which is defined in a .less file. Here are the entire contents of the .less file:

```
/** audio playing text. includes font and cursor*/
.aa {
    cursor: url(images/headphones.cur);
}
```

I have also tried using span to call the class "aa", but to be honest this is new territory for me so I may be way off with how I'm going about this.

This is the path for the .less file:

```
templates/rt_spectral/less/template-custom.less
```

And for the cursor file:

```
images/headphones.cur
```

Any thoughts on what is going on would be a huge help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks so much for the quick response Jarno.
I got this taken care of, but I had to add some other things that I hadn't come across before.
Here is my .less file now:

```
.aa {cursor: url(/images/listen.cur), progress !important;}
```

It took a long time to get anything to work properly, and it wasn't until I added

```
progress !important
```

that the cursor changed. I understand !important, but I couldn't find anything on progress !important, although there is no effect without it.
Thanks again! Nothing would have worked without your relative path help.

Comment: Somewhere at w3c they state that: "Note: Always specify a generic cursor at the end of the list, in case none of the URL-defined cursors can be used". Though they do not state this specifically but it looks like it should always be at least two cursors specified if the first is an `url()` one. In other words a minimal safe case should be `cursor: url(...), auto;`

Answer (score 1):

Based on the paths you're providing the path in your CSS is incorrect and should be:

```
.aa {
    cursor: url(../../../images/headphones.cur);
}
```