# Overriding CSS with .less in Joomla

Tags: css, less, joomla2.5, overriding

I am trying to use .less to modify a Joomla Gantry template. The text I'm trying to change with the "aa" class has linked audio, so the whole text shows up in blue color, which I am trying to change to dark brown. Here what I'm working with in my .less file:

```
.aa {
    cursor: url(/images/listen.cur), progress !important;
    color: @2E1507;
}
```

It's very simple, but I couldn't make the cursor change before without "progress !important", which doesn't make sense to me.
Now I am trying to change the color, but I can't find a way. Is there something important that I'm missing in trying to change these styles?

Comment: `color: @2E1507;` - did you mean `#2E1507;`?

Comment: also don't miss my comment about two cursors [there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20452436/2712740)

Answer (score 1):

I think @seven-phases-max provide you the right answer in the first place. `!important` in LESS has the same meaning as in CSS. You will use `!important` to overrule the [CSS specificity rules](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/). In most cases it is not a good idea to use !important, try to find the a selector with a higher specificity instead. Read also: http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/. One reason to use `!important` mentioned here will be utility classes. Maybe this is why you choose to use it here too.

`progress` sets your cursor type, see http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp. Cause you already use a `url()` for this, `progress` should not have any effect (`auto` is the default style).

Note if you need `!important` to set your cursor, you probably also will need it to set your color: `color: #2E1507 !important;`

When using a mixin in LESS you can set the !important; for all your properties once like:

```
.importantaudio(){
    cursor: url(/images/listen.cur), progress;
    color: #2E1507;
}

.aa{ .importantaudio() !important;}
```

CSS (result):

```
.aa {
  cursor: url(/images/listen.cur), progress !important;
  color: #2E1507 !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. With this code the cursor still changes but the color doesn't. I'll get to work finding the selectors and post the solution once I have it.

Comment: could you create a fiddle or bootply, with your css / html to show the problem? You will need `.aa:link` in stead of `.aa` maybe.